# SQL query using count and greater than

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm still learning.

How would I make this query work

```
mysql> select publisher
    -> from books
    -> where count(publisher) > 3;
```

The syntax is not correct, but I want to know how to find the name of the publisher where the number of (times that publisher appears in my table) is greater than 3.

Thanks

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `GROUP BY Publisher` and a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Publisher
FROM Books
GROUP BY Publisher
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is TSQL but will probably give you what you need..

```
SELECT Publisher, SUM(1) [Count]
FROM Books
GROUP BY Publisher
HAVING SUM(1) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

the most simple way to do it is using subquery:

```
mysql> select publisher
-> from books
-> where 3 < (select count(publisher) from books);
```